# Problema con formulario con llave foránea

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con los campos: `numero`, `fechaCreacion`, `fechaVencimiento`, `condiciones`, `subtotal` `iva`,`total` ,`observaciones`, `estado`, `Usuario_idUsuario` y `Proveedor _numeroIdent`.

De esos datos `Usuario_idUsuario` y `Proveedor_numeroIdent` son llaves foráneas

El problema es que cuando inserto los datos, estos no se registran en la base de datos.

Este es mi código:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php'; 

$numero = $_POST["numero"]; 
$fechac = $_POST["fechacreacion"]; 
$fechav = $_POST["fechavencimiento"]; 
$con = $_POST["condiciones"]; 
$sub = $_POST["subtotal"]; 
$iva = $_POST["iva"]; 
$total = $_POST["total"]; 
$observaciones = $_POST["observaciones"]; 
$es = $_POST["estado"]; 
$idus = $_POST["Usuario_id_idUsuario"]; 
$idp = $_POST["Proveedor_numeroIdent"];

$insertar ="INSERT INTO pedido(numero,fechaCreacion,fechaVencimiento,condiciones,subtotal,iva,total,observaciones,estado,Usuario_idUsuario,Proveedor_numeroIdent)VALUES ('$numero','$fechac','$fechav','$con','$sub','$iva','$total','$observaciones','$idus','$idp')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

if(!$resultado){
  echo 'Error al llenar formulario';
} else {
  echo 'Se ha llenado el formulario con exito';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Y no te sale error al llenar formulario ?, si son llaves foraneas el id del usuario y el proveedor ya deben existir en sus respectivas tablas, asi lo tienes ?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el mensaje de error?

Comment: Si, me sale error al llenar formulario.  Si, ya existen en sus respectivas tablas. Qué podria hacer?

Comment: para que te muestre el error añade esto cuando te genere error:

`echo mysqli_error($resultado);`

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/45619)

Comment: Añadí lo que dijiste  y me aparece este error Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\Pedido\Pedido.php on line 26

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas un var_dump($_POST) y no los envíes

Answer (score 2):

Es muy importante que tu código no sólo funcione, sino que el mismo sea seguro, de forma que los datos no sean expuestos al uso de código malicioso como puede ser la Inyección SQL.

Lo de la Inyección SQL es un tema complejo, pero que merita un poco de atención, ya que atañe a la seguridad de nuestros datos. Al final te dejo algunos enlaces.

Para evitarla, una de las prácticas recomendadas es el uso de **consultas preparadas**, las cuales consisten en crear instrucciones SQL independientes de los datos que se envían. De esto modo, se envía al manejador de BD por una parte la instrucción SQL (en este caso usando signos de interrogación `?` ) y por otra parte los datos en sí (en este caso usando `bind_param->`). Hay otras formas de hacerlo. Y se puede usar también PDO.

Nótese que en el método `bind_param` se pasan los datos almacenados en cada variable: `$numero,$fechac,$fechav,$con,$sub,$iva,$total,$observaciones,$idus,$idp` en el mismo orden en que aparecen en el `INSERT INTO ...` , también se debe especificar de qué tipo es cada dato que se está pasando, mediante las letras `s` o `i`. Para más detalles sobre `bind_param` [puedes consultar el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Un código más seguro, en tu caso, usando consultas preparadas, sería más o menos así:

```
/*
 * Cadena de inserción sin pasar directamente los valores, sino usando ?
 * IMPORTANTE: Debe haber tantos signos ? como nombres de columna
 *             Debe haber también la misma cantidad de valores en el bind_param
*/

$insertar ="
   INSERT INTO pedido 
   (numero,fechaCreacion,fechaVencimiento,condiciones,subtotal,iva,total,observaciones,estado,Usuario_idUsuario,Proveedor_numeroIdent) 
   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

/* Preparar la consulta */
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($insertar);

/* Puesto que prepare devuelve false si hay un error
 * podemos evaular tal condición directamente del modo siguiente
*/
if (!$resultado) {
      echo "No se pudieron insertar los datos. Error: ".$conexion->error;
} else {

/*
 * MUY IMPORTANTE: Las letras issiiiisii  indicarían el tipo de dato
 * de las columnas numero, fechaCreacion,fechaVencimiento,condiciones,subtotal,
 * iva,total,observaciones,estado,Usuario_idUsuario,Proveedor_numeroIdent
 * tal y como están declarados en la base de datos
 * en el ejemplo lo he puesto de forma intuitiva, debes verificarlo
 * y cambiar lo que haga falta 
 * (ver enlace precedente por si hubiera otro tipo de datos distinto de s o i)
 * s indica un tipo de dato varchar, fecha, etc... i indica un tipo de dato numérico
 * TAMBIÉN IMPORTANTE: Debe haber tantos valores como los indicados más arriba
 * por los signos ? y cada columna debe coincidir
 * Lo que hace bind_param es pasar aparte los valores a insertar
 * a fin de evitar la Inyección SQL, como se ha explicado más arriba
*/

     $resultado->bind_param('issiiiisii', $numero,$fechac,$fechav,$con,$sub,$iva,$total,$observaciones,$idus,$idp);

     /* Ejecutar la inserción */  
     $resultado->execute();

     /* 
        *Un una inserción hay que consultar affected_rows
        *para saber si realmente se insertaron filas y cuántas
     */
     $filasCreadas=$conexion->affected_rows;
     echo "Se insertaron un total de $filasCreadas registros";

}
```

Si la conexión está bien no debería tener problemas a la hora de insertar. Aunque yo, en mi caso, crearía una función de verificación usando los índices únicos para verificar si el registro existe antes de insertarlo, pero eso es ya otra cuestión.

---

Recomiendo que le dediques algunos minutos a entender el problema de la Inyección SQL. Para ello, te puede servir lo siguiente:

- [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)
- [Manual de PHP: Inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Hice lo que mencionaste, pero me sale este error Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\Pedido\Pedido.php on line 40

Comment: @Oddinx He mejorado el código, haciendo algunos cambios y dando más detalles en comentarios del mismo código. Debes verificar que la conexión a la bd funciona, que el nombre de la tabla y de columnas son correctos y que cada dato corresponde con su tipo y con el valor que intentas insertar. Debe haber tantos bind y valores como columnas y signos ?, de lo contrario la consulta fallará.